# How can I create a for/while loop for following product formation?

Tags: php, .net, entity-framework, product

I am using database for retrieving products.

I want to display product in following pattern.

What can be the php Or .net loop code for this ? Help.

```
<div class="big-row">
        <div class="first-row-left">
            <div class="product-1a">Product1</div>
            <div class="product-1a">Product2</div>
            <div class="product-1a">Product3</div>
            <div class="product-1b">Product4</div>
            <div class="product-1b">Product5</div>
            <div class="product-1b">Product6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="first-row-right">
            <div class="bigproduct-right">Product7</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="single-row">
        <div class="product-single-row">Product8</div>
        <div class="product-single-row">Product9</div>
        <div class="product-single-row">Product10</div>
        <div class="product-single-row">Product11</div>
        <div class="product-single-row">Product12</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="big-row">
        <div class="first-row-left">
     <?php    
        for($i = 0, $intSize = sizeof($arr); $i < $intSize ; $i++){ 
     ?>         <div class="product-1a"><?php echo $arr['product']; ?></div>
     <?php 
         }
     ?> 
         </div>
```

A small example of for loop

Comment: Any Dummy user would know this, How can I Implement for remaining pattern ?

Comment: Your question lacks clarity. Is it like the 7th product goes on to class="first-row-right"?                                                        if yes you can put an if Condition inside the for loop